# check current time is greater than defined time rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to check it my current time is greater than a defined time.

My start time could be anytime from day:

Like, `Time.now.strftime("%I:%M %p")` gives `"11:17 AM"`

I need to see if this time is greater than `"04:00 PM"` of same day

Means if any point my `current time` is greater than same day of `04:00 PM`
I have tried:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now.strftime("%I:%M %p"), "04:00:00 PM") %>
```

but its not working as expected.

any possible way to get this?

Plus please could anyone tell best practices as well to calculate the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use beginning_of_day and then manoeuvre to the target time by adding hours.

```
If Time.now > Time.now.beginning_of_day + 16.hours
```

The fact that `Time.now` includes a date component doesn't matter, since it's the same date on both sides of the comparison.